# AutoFixture - customization using ISpecimenBuilder derived class - issues with casting request to PropertyInfo

Tags: .net-core, autofixture

I am using AutoFixture 4.17 in .NET 6
I am trying to create my own customization generator for DateTime
I read several tutorials and my code base on them.

It was said, that request parameter to Create method should be of type PropertyInfo so we can further analyze it. However, it is of type SeededRequest having inside Request property of anonymous type.
What is the best way now to analyze this Request field? Can I cast it somehow? To what type?

[image]

**UPDATE:**
I found a solution by casting it to dynamic type:

```
dynamic dyn = request as dynamic;
dynamic req = dyn.Request as dynamic;
if(req.Name != "DateTime")
```

but I'm not sure if this is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to learn more about [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection?view=net-7.0) and [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching) in .NET.

AutoFixture uses reflection a lot to be able to generate test data.

Here's a sample that might help you get started.

```cs
[Fact]
public void Foo()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Customizations.Add(new MyDateTimeGenerator());

    var time = fixture.Create<DateTime>();

    Assert.Equal(new DateTime(2011, 12, 13), time);
}

public class MyDateTimeGenerator : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var isDateTimeRequest = request is Type type
            && type == typeof(DateTime);

        if (!isDateTimeRequest)
            return new NoSpecimen();

        return new DateTime(2011, 12, 13);
    }
}
```